# How can I find posts with excessive numbers of comments?

Tags: discussion, search, moderator-tools

As a mod, one of the things that I do is clean up comment discussions and diatribes on old posts.  It makes the site more friendly, and to be honest gives me a warm fuzzy.

Is there a way *as a moderator* to identify posts with more than *N* comments?

Comment: I'm assuming you want up-to-date, live on the site searches, otherwise I'd suggest the data explorer.

Comment: Isn't an automated flag issued if a question attracts too many comments?

Comment: @ChrisF That would be best.  Data explorer is ok, but it's hard to tell what's already been cleaned up.

Comment: @Bobby That's only for really outlandish numbers of comments, more than ten I think.

Comment: On Stack Overflow the automated flag kicks in when a post gets more than 20 comments in 3 days.  I don't know if it's the same on other sites.

Comment: I wonder if you could do this with an [API call](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage)?  I'm not extremely familiar with the API, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10):

Under the "Review" menu under "Tools" under "Stats" is a section where you can see the most commented posts on your site from the last 30 days. This isn't perfect, but its a good place to start.

Here is a link to it on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=stats&daterange=last30days).